# What does the webroot refer to?

Tags: php

So, I've looked around quite a few questions around Stack Overflow and many of them mention the "webroot" - when looking for a specific definition of it, though, I've been unable to find one. 
Does the webroot refer to the very base file (as in "App:) in my structural example below. Or does it refer to where the file you are talking about relatively? I.e. if I was talking about balance.php would it refer to view?

```
app
--Protected
______view
__________balance.php
----------level.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the webroot, aka document root, is where "publicly accessible" files start in a website.

E.g. your site has a file, and url pointing at that file:

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html/private/downloads/cutekittens.jpg
           http://example.com/private/downloads/cutekittens.jpg
                             ^---where the document root starts
```

Note where the two start corresponding. Everything "above" that point (/home/site/example.com/html) is OUTSIDE of the site's document root. Anything inside that `.../html` directory is inside the document root, and therefore accessible by browser from outside the server.

Note that this doesn't take into consideration any server-side aliases, rewriting, routing, etc...

Comment: Yeah, typo. sorry/fixed.

Comment: In the case of Yii would it then be protected?

Answer (score 0):

It will be the base directory where web-accessible files go, usually called public_html, httpdocs, htdocs or wwwroot.

Comment: In case people interpret this as meaning you can only have one site per server, it is worth pointing out that one can have many web roots per server: one per vhost.